# Can a user having 1 reputation on Stack Overflow offer a bounty?

Tags: discussion

According to *https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties*, the privilege to keep a bounty starts from reputation of 75, so I came across this question on Stack Overflow:

*[Kivy sounds do not play on android device even though they play fine on laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64014568/kivy-sounds-do-not-play-on-android-device-even-though-they-play-fine-on-laptop)*

It has a bounty of 100, and the user has a reputation 1,

**My opinion:**

I guess you have to have 75 reputation points in any of the communities.

Comment: They did have a [reputation of 101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7301632/maithreya-sitaraman?tab=reputation) (association bonus) and spend 100 of it on that bounty. That's why they have only 1 rep *now*.

Comment: okay, now i get it, then what will happen after the bounty is awarded to someone, does his reputation go in negative or will it be 1?

Comment: Nothing will happen. The bounty was already subtracted from their reputation.

Comment: oh, ok so lets say he wants to add a bounty for another question now, can he? or he should reach 75 reputation again to do that?

Comment: They would need to gain enough reputation again first before they could set another bounty.

Comment: ok so what will happen if the bounty question is unanswered before 7 days?

Comment: The bounty will not be awarded. OP will have lost the 100 rep.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a bounty is offering some of your own reputation as a reward to someone else. You can't give someone reputation you don't have any more than you can pay someone with money you don't have.

You need to have enough reputation on the target site, since reputation and privileges are on a per-site basis. That's because being familiar with one site doesn't necessarily mean that you're particularly familiar with how another site works (or that you know anything about the topic).

The exception being the association bonus, because being familiar with how Stack Exchange works "in general" does confer at least a basic knowledge of how other sites *might* work. This bonus is enough to confer privileges that you likely already know how to use based on your knowledge of other sites (like commenting and voting).